# Unable to connect Oracle 11g first time

Tags: oracle11g, windows-7-x64

I have just installed Oracle 11g 64bit on Windows 7. Since I am using Oracle 11g first time before i have worked on oracle 9i on windows xp so facing some problem. When i open SQL Plus a screen appeared like this
SQL*PLUS: Release
Copyright
Enter user-name: 
Now i want to know the user-name and password for this screen. I tried scott/tiger but not working. In fact the error message it get is ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error

Answer (score 1):

username : system

password : password which you gave while installing oracle

I guess Scott is locked by default in 11g.